How do we know if correlation have an effect or model fit data
Assuming there is an infinite amount of functions that can be applied to a dataset. Then one of them must perfectly match our data and allow for predictions, just by chance.
If so, do these the patterns really tell us something? Or do we have to understand why the pattern occurs? For instance: Weather. Which can be predicted okay-ishly and can be compared to other forecasts. But how do we know that this model is correct and not just a random fit to our data.
For instance  we may say that the Western values are the best because the west is great without understanding how those values actually helped the west become great. But on the other hands person may argue that the west is great because of environmental things like having the same climate in most places which help spreading the same tech. How do we know which correlation is right.

I do not think that "comparative philosophy" is the "philosophy of comparison"...

This doesn't seem coherent. I'm voting to close.

Regarding the first para: Models in Science.

Weather forecast are based on mathematical models: very huge systems of equations. The development of more sophisticated models as well as the availability of huge computing power are massively improving reliability of forecats.

The example of a "correlation" between Western weather and Western value is out of scope and quite weird...

@MauroALLEGRANZA In "Guns, Germs, and Steel", Jared Diamond also argues in a similar way.

Yes correlation doesn't imply causation and finding a correlation in data could be a coincidence.
So with regards to avoiding to fall for pure randomness or coincidence, you could first employ math. Gathering more data already reduces the amount of functions that just randomly fit. Idk if you have 2 data points you could fit almost any function to that if you have a billion over a wide array of possible parameters there are far fewer functions that fit that. Also there are various tests for correlations and methods to make estimates of how significant or insignificant that correlation is.
Next up would be science. That is you'd just test it. If your theory is good it will work in the real world as predicted. If it doesn't, then your correlation might not have been significant or it could have been a local anomaly, that only works in a narrow set of parameters.
Now beyond the mathematical formalization you'd often like to have a translation to real world properties, so not just answering "WHAT is going to happen next", but trying to explain "HOW it is going to happen", the latter would enable to mimic and influence the process.
So somewhat the difference between asking a "black box" mechanism about the weather which accurately tells you "rain or no rain" or understanding the process well enough to see the indicators for yourselves that lead to a result of "rain" or "no rain".
The latter would allow for a much better compression of data as you could build your models from your knowledge while otherwise you'd need a new model for every process that you want to model.
So the holy grail of that reductionism would be to understand the interactions between the smallest particles in the universe so that you could build an understanding of all the rest by stacking them up like LEGO.
Conversely if your theories are contradicted by data then they end up being worthless and the more you build upon them, the more that collapses like a house of cards or the more digging you'd have to do as to which parts of your model could survive that and which are plain dead.
So realistically the only thing "real" in science is data. The models, fitted functions and explanations are just a convenience wrapper to better visualize and compress the existing data as taking billions of "if x then y" case tables to your problem is unhandy and impractical.
So yeah explanations and fit functions can be wrong and often enough are. The question is somewhat: Does that matter? Like for a whole lot of people, it doesn't really matter whether the explanation is correct, what matters is that the correlation is trustworthy, regardless of why that is the case. So if you give sacrifice water and food at an altar to pray to the gods to let your farm animals live (and your farm animals come by and eat that) or if you give it to them to directly it hardly matters in terms of input and output so, input -> give them water and output -> them staying alive remains a somewhat accurate prediction.
Though if you take the wrong path and build shrines and pray rather than supply food and water, then that makes sense within the narrative of pleasing the gods, but it might no longer lead to keeping the farm stock alive. So in that case you'd come to realize that correlation did not imply causation and that the cause might be something different.
So yeah if real world experience contradicts scientific models then, the scientific method would reject the model and relegate it back to the drawing board to find a better fit, rather than reject the new data. That being said one should also be careful to reject a model based on outliers, like just because there are a few exceptions to a rule doesn't mean it's not still a useful heuristic that works most of the time. But it would require some more research as to why there were outliers. Whether they are consistent and reproducible, whether they are localized and match with a narrow set of parameters or whether they apply universally, they might have been ignored as outliers, but occur frequent though in low numbers and stuff like that.
So that would be new data added to the pool.
Another example might be to train a model to detect hands. Like you could show it loads of picture of hands and if it get better over time you might think that this has to do with detecting the shape and texture of a hand and that it would just be universally applicable to all humans. Though if your test data was all white hands and it fails on black and brown hands or those that are within gloves, you might come to realize that it wasn't actually detecting hands as much as the color patterns and that the overlap was just coincidence. Though it might still work where the color pattern matches, you now have an upgraded intuition what it looks for and you have an idea how you could train it better to be more universal, that is more diverse datasets for example or training of localized versions.

The problem is that, the number of sample you need depends on the nature of your data sometimes it can be confusing  when something is sure or not and it effected by psychology

@daniel People have done a lot of statistics to figure when it's reasonable to say a correlation actually exists, and much of what scientists do is to try to eliminate confounding variables, coincidental correlations and inverse causation, such that we can have reasonable confidence of causation. It is a problem, but we've gotten pretty good at solving it, and at knowing how well it's been solved.

I now found this whcih explain it well https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination

@daniel Yeah sample size determination is an important concept, on the one hand every sample takes time and money so you'd like to have as little as possible on the other hand most statistics only works for large numbers. So getting samples of sizes that are significant already is some mathematical art, where a lot of thought is spent upon.

You simply don't.
You assume the correlation to be true based on:

The quality of your work / understanding of the problem
The quality and quantity of your data

If we want to analyze the simplest thing for example eating and hunger. You could assume than a positive correlation of hunger with respects to eating: more hunger > more eating. And you would be correct if you had a full plate of food when you were hungry. However if you add money into the equation (or any other varibale), the logic breaks and the correlation does not work anymore. That is why it is limited to our comprehension of the model. The more data you add, the more the "old" correlation is false.
Claiming that a complete understanding of a problem based on the data is false, because that would mean perfect data and perfect understanding of it.
Correlation is not a prediction. It must taken into account that it is limited to our comprehension of the problem and it is only a tool to try to understand better the behaviour of our data. And it will change if we add new data.
